# UnwantedCommunicationReportingExtension API calling failing

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurl, ios-extensions, apple-app-site-associate

I want to add [UnwantedCommunicationReportingExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/sms_and_call_spam_reporting/) to my iOS app to report calls from Call History. I created UI for that and I can see the report button on Call History and Extention is opening. I have followed every step to make sure UnwantedCommunicationReportingExtension will work with my app. But the API call is failing when I press the done button. Let me list here

1. Adding a new target UnwantedCommunicationReportingExtension to my project
2. Adding API endpoint ('''https://api.mycompany.net/call/v2/main/report''') to Info.plist

```
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtension</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ILClassificationExtensionNetworkReportDestination</key>
                <string>https://api.mycompany.net/call/v2/main/report</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
            <string>MainInterface</string>
            <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.identitylookup.classification-ui</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

3. Added classificationreport to Associate domain in Capability section.
   `classificationreport:api.mycompany.net`
4. Created an **apple-app-site-association** file without json extension and returned this when **api.mycompany.net** called. I don't know whether to add app's bundle id or the extension's bundle id. So added both. Complete **apple-app-site-association** below

```
{
    "classificationreport": {
        "apps": [
            "XXXXXX.com.company.appname.CallReport",
            "XXXXXX.com.company.appname"
        ]
    }
}
```

5. I checked the following website to ensure the file can be accessed. Both display the file

```
https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/api.mycompany.net 
https://api.mycompany.net/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

But I cannot call API '''https://api.mycompany.net/call/v2/main/report'''. It always fails with the following error

[image: error_image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I tried for a week and was exhausted.